# Process a list of instructions and output the max value reached

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, virtual-machine

Inputs looks like this

```
b inc 5 if a > 1
a inc 1 if b < 5
c dec -10 if a >= 1
c inc -20 if c == 10
```

I am concerned that I need to declare `__max__` as `global` (but not `__registers__`). Any other recommendation on this Python script for a beginner ?

```
import sys
import re

steps = 0

__registers__ = []
__max__ = None

class Instruction:
    def __init__(self, string):
        # Group 1 is the register name,
        # Group 2 is inc or dec,
        # Group 3 is the amount to increase or decrease,
        # Group 4 is the full condition
        # Group 5 is the name of register against which the condition is tested,
        # Group 6 is the operand of the condition,
        # Group 7 is the numerical value of the second term of the condition
        regex = "(\w+)\s(inc|dec)\s(-*\d+)\sif\s((\w+)\s([^\w\s]+)\s(-*\d+))"
        regex_string = re.search(regex, string)
        if regex_string:
            self.name = regex_string.group(1)
            __registers__.append(Register(self.name, 0))
            self.oper = regex_string.group(2)
            self.amount = int(regex_string.group(3))
            self.condition = regex_string.group(4)
            self.tested_register = regex_string.group(5)
            self.test_operand = regex_string.group(6)
            self.test_value = int(regex_string.group(7))

    def process_instruction(self):
        # We do the test : 
        p =  str(find(self.tested_register).value)
        condition = self.condition.replace(self.tested_register, p)
        if eval(condition):
            # We apply the inc / dec amount : 
            reg = find(self.name)
            # print(reg.value)
            if self.oper == "inc":
                reg.value = reg.value + self.amount
            else:
                reg.value = reg.value - self.amount
            # print(reg.value)
            global __max__
            if __max__ is None or reg.value > __max__:
                __max__ = reg.value

class Register:
    def __init__(self, name, value):
        self.name = name
        self.value = value

def find(register_name):
    for register in __registers__:
        if register.name == register_name:
            return register 

def get_max():
    max = None
    for regi in __registers__:
        if max is None or regi.value > max:
            max = regi.value
    return max

def main(arguments):
    fileName = sys.argv[1]
    global instructions
    instructions = [Instruction(line.rstrip('\n')) for line in open(fileName)]
    # print(__registers__)
    # print(len(__registers__))
    global __max__
    for instru in instructions:
        instru.process_instruction()
    print(get_max())
    print(__max__)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv[1:]))
```

Comment: Because you're assigning to `__max__`, and simply operating on `__registers__` using `list.append`. As far as I'm aware, '\_\_registers\_\_' isn't a documented magic attribute in CPython. Don't invent your own!

Comment: Aaah... That makes no sense. In both ways I am 'writing' to the object, modifying it.

Comment: I should have named my globals max_ and registers_?

Comment: Consider how Python interprets your code. Say you have some global variable `foo = [42]`, and you're inside a function (or anything with local scope, really). Let's say you're assigning `foo = [42, 43]`. Now, *locally*, `foo` will be `[42, 43]`. However, once you exit the local scope, it will be destroyed.

Comment: If you call `foo.append(43)` instead, the interpreter will notice that there's no locally defined `foo`. It will instead look in the global scope and find `foo == [42]`. By using `global <name>`, you're simply telling Python: 'assign this to the global variable <name>, instead of the local variable <name>'.

Comment: `max` is a Python builtin, so to avoid shadowing, yes, use `max_`. Since `registers` isn't defined in the Python standard, you don't need to add a trailing underscore.

Comment: @Coal_ I am still not getting it. I am calling `__registers__` from Instruction's __init__ : from what you say with `append()`, Python pulls the global variable because it does not find a local one. But  whi it's not doing so for __max__ ?

Comment: Because assigning to `__max__` is ambiguous. If `__registers__` doesn't exist locally, Python does a global lookup. Because assignment doesn't require a variable to exist beforehand, it could be assigned to either locally or globally. The `global` keyword clears up the ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

As the comment threads make clear, the mystery about `global` goes away when you recognize the difference between *accessing* a variable from an outer scope (like your did with `__registers___` and *assigning* to a variable whose name happens to also exist in an outer scope (what happened with `__max__`)

You can simplify a good bit of this by exploiting exactly this behavior.  If you store your registers in a module-level dictionary, you can access that dictionary in any part of the code without having to pass it around. Since you don't *assign* the dictionary -- you just access it -- you don't need to declare it global.  So in you case you could eliminate the `find()` function because you'd just grab a register value out of the dictionary.

```
 REGISTERS = {'a': 0, 'b': 1}

 def increment(reg, val):
     REGISTERS[reg] += val
```

would be an example.  In this case we can be a bit lazy and use a [dictionary comprehension](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/python-dictionary-comprehension) -- a shorthand way to fill out a dictionary with keys from 'a' to 'z' and values of all zeros:

```
import string  # the string module has a builtin for the ascii alphabet
REGISTERS = {char: 0 for char in string.ascii_lowercase}
```

So you don't need a register class -- you just manipulate the values in the dictionary for each register.

To do the instruction parsing, you can simplify things a good bit by eliminating the regex and simply using Python's builtin string `split()` function, which will take a string like  'b inc 5 if a > 1' and turn it into ['b', 'inc', '5', 'if', 'a', '>', '1'] without any extra work (this would not be appropriate if any of your directives had spaces in them -- but they don't seem to in this example).  That gives you 7 tokens -- your comment here was very useful -- 3 describing the tests you want to apply and three describing the operation to perform in the test passes (#3, the `if`, is basically ignorable).

With everything already parsed out, you really don't need to use classes.  The `Instruction` class does only two things: it applies the test in the last three tokens, and if that test is true it uses the instructions in the first three tokens to change the register.  Python has a handy built-in way to do what you're trying to do -- capturing common operations like addition or comparison.  The [operator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html) module has a bunch of functions which correspond to the basic operations. For example 'inc' corresponds to `operator.iadd` which is basically a += b expressed as a function.  '>' becomes `operator.gt`, a function that returns true if the first of its arguments is greater than the second.

That would get rid of much of the logic in your `Instruction` class.  Another module level 'global' dictionary is an easy way to map the strings to the operator,  simplifying both the process of parsing -- no conditional checks, just dictionary lookups -- and of running the tests.  So, first a dictionary to do the mapping:

```
# match operator functions to string identifiers
OPERANDS = {
    'inc': operator.iadd,
    'dec': operator.isub,
    '>': operator.gt,
    '>=': operator.ge,
    '<': operator.lt,
    '<=': operator.le,
    '==': operator.eq,
    '!=': operator.ne
}
```

and with that in place the functions to use these operators are very simple. If you want to apply some operation to a register, you get the value from the REGISTERS dictionary, the operator from the OPERANDS dictionary, then call the operator with your value:

```
def apply_value(register, opstring, valstring):
    operator = OPERANDS[opstring]
    value = float(valstring)
    orig = REGISTERS[register]
    REGISTERS[register] = operator(orig, value)
```

doing the test ('is this larger than 5' or whatever) is equally simple:

```
def condition(register, teststring, testval):
    check = OPERANDS[teststring]
    value = float(testval)
    existing = REGISTERS[register]
    return check(existing, value)
```

So as you parse a line of instructions, you just run condition function on the last three tokens ("a > 5") and if it's true, run the `apply_value` function on the first three:

```
    with open(filename, 'rt') as fileread:
        for directive in fileread:
            tokens = directive.split()  # [3] is always 'if', so ignored
            if condition(tokens[4], tokens[5], tokens[6]):
                apply_value(tokens[0], tokens[1], tokens[2])
```

If you run that on all your directives you'll see the register values going up and down.  Python also has an easy built-in way to find the maximum value in a series -- so to get the largest register value it's just

```
    max_value = max(REGISTERS.values())
```

with no need for you to track the max value manually.

Putting it all together it might look like this:

```
import sys
import operator
import string

# match operator functions to string identifiers
OPERANDS = {
    'inc': operator.iadd,
    'dec': operator.isub,
    '>': operator.gt,
    '>=': operator.ge,
    '<': operator.lt,
    '<=': operator.le,
    '==': operator.eq,
    '!=': operator.ne
}

# REGISTERS is a dictionary with names as keys, initialized to 0's
REGISTERS = {char: 0 for char in string.ascii_lowercase}


def apply_value(register, opstring, valstring):
    operator = OPERANDS[opstring]
    value = float(valstring)
    orig = REGISTERS[register]
    REGISTERS[register] = operator(orig, value)


def check_condition(register, teststring, testval):
    check = OPERANDS[teststring]
    value = float(testval)
    existing = REGISTERS[register]
    return check(existing, value)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    filename = sys.argv[-1]
    with open(filename, 'rt') as fileread:
        for directive in fileread:
            tokens = directive.split()  # [3] is always 'if', so ignored
            if check_condition(tokens[4], tokens[5], tokens[6]):
                apply_value(tokens[0], tokens[1], tokens[2])


    max_value = max(REGISTERS.values())
    for name, value in REGISTERS.items():
        if value == max_value:
            print ("highest register:", name, value)
```

As with many problems in Python, the rich offerings in the standard library often let you get away with just simple functions instead of lots of custom classes.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if this is not suitable, but why don't you just this? (Using input instead of reading file)

```
a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t, u, v, w, x, y, z = [0] * 26
while True: # Reading Input
    try:
        # Replace 'inc', 'dec' with '+=' and '-='
        # Also split string into 2 parts
        string = input().replace('inc', '+=').replace('dec', '-=').split(' if ')
        # print (string)

        # Rearrange string
        string = 'if ' + string[1] + ': ' + string[0]

        # Execute string
        exec(string)
    except:
        break

print (a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t, u, v, w, x, y, z)
```